# Loading custom classes in Codeception acceptance tests

Tags: php, testing, webdriver, codeception

I'm testing the frontend of a large project with Codeception's acceptance tests.  So far using the WebDriver module has worked well, but when trying to use the tried-and-true `require` statement to import other files the test-runner doesn't run.

I've tried using the `bootstrap.php` file to put the `require` statements, as well as putting them directly into the test file itself, but with the same consequences: *the tests don't run.*

What can I do to be able to import PHP files and use classes from my application in Codeception?

EDIT:

There are no errors output when running `codecept run acceptance`

EDIT #2:

I've gone ahead and used the `_bootstrap.php` file at the top level of `tests/`.  `require` etc. work there.  I've given up on using the Autoload class and have gone to using `spl_autoload_register` like so:

```
spl_autoload_register( function ( $class_name ) {
    $models_path = __DIR__ . '/models/' . $class_name . '.php';  
    $services_path = __DIR__ . '/services/' . $class_name . '.php';

    if ( file_exists( $models_path) ) {
        require( $models_path );
    } else if ( file_exists( $services_path ) ) {
        require( $services_path );
    }
} );
```

I know it's hacky, and may have to do with my understanding of PHP's namespacing and PSR-0/4 suggestions. Feel free to answer this if you have a working solution more in line with Codeception's system, please!

Comment: Please be more specific than `the tests don't run.` - please provide error messages, stack traces.

Comment: It is a bit odd that you are trying to include files in acceptance tests, they communicate with website over HTTP and don't need to include any files from the website.

Comment: I'm trying to confirm that data is actually saved through a private api, and there are pre-built classes for handling the data I'd like to use.

Comment: `the tests don't run` is exactly that, it goes back to the console, no errors or stack traces.

Comment: Are you using a full path to the files you want to include?